# Is there a way to assert a certain value returned in an XML response file in Jmeter

Tags: xml, soap, jmeter, automated-tests

I have created a SOAP request  Jmeter 
I added an XML assertion to my test plan
But it's not enough for me 
Is there a way to assert a certain value in the response XML 
Let's say a certain value in a certain tag in the response XML

Comment: If you want to check for specific tags, you can use Regular Expression Extractor in your test plan. http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML Assertion checks response against [XSD schema](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_intro.asp), the test element you are looking for is [XPath Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Assertion).

You will be able to add checks based on [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) language queries and validate response against expected values to conditionally fail samplers where there is a mismatch.

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article to learn more about different JMeter assertion types.